# Removed node in dialog is not removed after first deployment

Tags: aem, jcr, jackrabbit-oak

AEM 6.1: I had a one cq:Dialog node with structure below:

```
+- myDialog
 |- cq:Dialog
  |- content
    |- layout
    |- items
     |- myTab
      |- somethingInside
```

I did a little change that adds two things and removes `myTab`. I have current structure in code:

```
+- myDialog
 |- cq:Dialog
  |- content
    |- layout
    |- items
     |- myNewTab
     |- myNewestTab
```

I created a zip package using AEM standard packaging and install it on author, then I get:

```
 +- myDialog
 |- cq:Dialog
  |- content
    |- layout
    |- items
     |- myTab
      |- somethingInside
     |- myNewTab
     |- myNewestTab
```

However, after the second deploy or even reinstalling package it removes `myTab` node and works okay. Is it a known AEM issue or I did something wrong here?

My _cq_dialog.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jcr:root xmlns:sling="http://sling.apache.org/jcr/sling/1.0"
          xmlns:cq="http://www.day.com/jcr/cq/1.0"
          xmlns:jcr="http://www.jcp.org/jcr/1.0"
          xmlns:nt="http://www.jcp.org/jcr/nt/1.0"
          jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
          sling:resourceType="cq/gui/components/authoring/dialog"
          jcr:title="Text &amp; Title">
    <content jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
             sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/foundation/container">
        <layout jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/foundation/layouts/tabs"
                type="nav" />
        <items jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured">
            <myNewTab jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                  sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/foundation/section"
                  jcr:title="New Tab">
                <layout jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                        sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/foundation/layouts/fixedcolumns" />
                <items jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured">
                    <column jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                            sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/foundation/container">
                        <items jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured">
                        </items>
                    </column>
                </items>
            </myNewTab>
            <myNewestTab jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                  sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/foundation/section"
                  jcr:title="Newest Tab">
                <layout jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                        sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/foundation/layouts/fixedcolumns" />
                <items jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured">
                    <column jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                            sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/foundation/container">
                        <items jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured">
                        </items>
                    </column>
                </items>
            </myNewestTab>
        </items>
    </content>
</jcr:root>
```

Comment: Can you please share the dialog xml here ..

Comment: Sure I did already :) Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It might possible that you have not saved it after removing the myTab node. Thus, when you had created a package, it contains all the three nodes i.e. myTab, myNewTab, myNewestTab.

Notice your dialog.xml does not contain any `<myTab>` element. Thus, if you reinstall it didn't created myTab node.

Try it again with more experiments and share if it happens again.

Hope it explains your point.
:)